# Algorithm for randomly generating polyhedrons?

Tags: computational-geometry, mathematics

I want to randomly generate polyhedrons which need not be convex. What is the most efficient way for doing so?

I can think of an algorithm for generating random convex polyhedrons, but am unable to figure out a way for generating non-convex ones. How to generate a general polyhedron?

Taking it a step further, generalising my question to an n dimension space, how to randomly generate bounded finite polytopes?

Comment: Do you have a requirement that all possible polyhedra have a non-zero probability of being generated? Do you require equal probability for each possible polyhedron? Your specific requirements may affect the range of solutions that are applicable.

Comment: For example, would combining 2 or more convex polyhedra to give a non-convex one be sufficient for your purposes?